# Unity C# Change pressed sprite from button

Tags: image, button, unity-game-engine, sprite

How do I change the sprite from a button when the button is pressed?
I already changed the normal sprite with: 
gameObject.GetComponent().sprite = Resources.Load  ("MineScreenImages/" + Ge.player.ActiveDiggingTool.DiggingToolId.ToString ()+"Idle");

I already tryed finding pressedSprite or something along the lines of spriteState but it didn't work.

Comment: gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().spriteState.pressedSprite  = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("imagename/"); Didn't work felt hoepful about this

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public Button bt;
public SpriteState st;

void Start () {
        bt.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = newspr;
        st.pressedSprite = newspr1;
        bt.spriteState = st;
}
```